# DataTable serverside processing search

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I want to add search option to my dataTable. I'm using 1.10.13 serverside processing option.

**here is the js code I have tried:**

```
  var thisTable = $('#users).DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "type": "GET",
            "url": "/user/userda",
            "dataSrc": "data",
            "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "dataType": "json",
            "processData": true
        },
        "fnDrawCallback": function () {
            console.log(this.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal());
        },
        "columns": [

            {"data": "name"},
            {"data": "email"},
            {"data": "company"},
            {"data": "usersgroup"},
            {"data": "regdate"}

        ]
    });
```

**below is my view search input:**

I want to bind below field with datatable and do the search. Please advice me

```
  <div class="filterPart">
        <label>Search</label>
        <input id="search" value="<?php echo $search; ?>" placeholder="Keyword" type="text" class="customfilters" />
    </div>
    <div class="filterPart lastLogin">
        <label>Registration</label>
        <input id="custom_registration_date1" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $registrationDateFrom; ?>"  data-target-input="registration_date1" name="custom_registration_date1" placeholder="From">
        <input id="custom_registration_date2" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $registrationDateTo; ?>"  data-target-input="registration_date2"  name="custom_registration_date2" placeholder="To">
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you aware that if you do server side search You must handle the total display numbers , page , sort , search text , total records in dB, currently showing number .. all these on your server code..

Comment: @Rajshekar Reddy : do I have to pass those value through my model ->controller to js . please advice

Comment: When you do search the plugin will post all these parameters to the URL you specify. You need to take into account of all the parameters and query your results.. If your result set is small I suggest you to go with local data or HTML table approach

Answer (score 0):

To perform global search using your external input:

```
$('#search').on('keyup click', function (){
    $('#users').DataTable().search(this.value).draw();
});
```

See [Global search](https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html) example for more details.

Comment: thanks. How can search date range with datepicker ? ex: coloum is reg_date and I want to add search filter with from and to. pls advice